# Static Nested Type

Tags: c#

So i have nested type classes that go something like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class User
    {
        private int id = 0;
        private string userId = "";
        private string userPassword = "";

        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        public string UserId
        {
            get { return userId; }
            set { userId = value; }
        }

        public string UserPassword
        {
            get { return userPassword; }
            set { userPassword = value; }
        }


        public User()
        {
            id = 0;
            userId = "";
            userPassword = "";
        }


        public static class SignonInfo
        {
            private static string sesstoken = "";
            private static DateTime sessstart = new DateTime();

            public static string SessToken
            {
                get { return sesstoken; }
                set { sesstoken = value; }
            }

            public static DateTime SessStart
            {
                get { return sessstart; }
                set { sessstart = value; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My end goal here was to be able to access the nested static class like this:

```
User user = new User();
string token = user.SignonInfo.SessToken;
```

I'm trying to avoid instantiating the class like this:

```
User.SignonInfo user = new User.SignonInfo()
```

I need to be able to access properties of both User and SignonInfo classes.

Could someone help me to get on track or slap me about and tell me i'm doing it all wrong?

TIA

Comment: If you try to compile the code the compiler is going to *exactly* what you're doing wrong.  Trust it; it knows what it's talking about.

Comment: Actually the above code compiles just fine, i'm just unable to access xxxxxx.SignonInfo.SessToken as i have described above.

Comment: One snippet compiles fine, the other doesn't.  So you can't do it the way that doesn't compile.  You can do it just fine when doing it the way that it compiles.  Either way, you clearly can get the answer to your question by simply compiling your code.  You don't need us to tell you what the compiler has already told you.

Comment: @Nugs: Read compiler error message and share your thoughts in a comment here.

Comment: I don't know guys. the only thing i get from the error is that SignonInfo should be an extension method. However, extension methods don't provide me the properties i need. I understand how to read compiler errors and did my homework on this before posting. I would not have posted if i did not need guidance of some kind outside of normal debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it's a static class, so an "instance" doesn't have access to it.  This is a good thing, as it prevents global state from masquerading as a well-encapsulated object.

I'd suggest making the nested class non-static, and having the`User` class create an instance as needed by the caller (maybe add a `public SignonInfo GetSignonInfo()` method.)

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful.

Comment: If you do this then the code won't have the semantics that the question states it's supposed to have.

Comment: Well, its the best response i have gotten thus far. At least now i know why i am wrong and have a suggestion of some sort to work with.

Comment: @Nugs Why in the world would you want an answer suggesting a solution that wouldn't work?  How is that even better than no answer at all?

Comment: @Servy my point is, you not being helpful. In all the time it has taken you to berate me and the other users on this post you could have just provided some guidance besides "go look at the compiler error"

Comment: @Nugs In the time it has taken you to berate me and others for trying to help you, you could have just read the compiler error that your code is generating, which tells you exactly why your code is wrong and how to fix it.  If you were to do this, you'd have the answer to your question in a matter of *seconds*, as opposed to the time you'll spend reading this post and not getting any solution to your problem, and in fact moving further from it.  Posting incorrect answers to a question isn't helpful; it's actively harmful.

Comment: I have not berated anyone. But since you asked - go untwist you panties and find some other poor sod to "help"...

Comment: Dude, @Servy, chill.  I promise you that Stack overflow will keep humming along without your policing :).  Maybe go for a walk or something

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to access your nested class as if it were a member of the instance of the outer class.

Change

`string token = user.SignonInfo.SessToken;`

to

`User.SignonInfo.SessToken;`

Note, that you do not get an instance of the static nested type per outer instance, there is only one for the entire outer class.

Comment: This is all information that's mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: No.  It's really not.

Comment: From the question, "I'm trying to avoid instantiating the class like this: `User.SignonInfo user = new User.SignonInfo()`"

Comment: The OP says the "end goal" is like `User user = new User();
string token = user.SignonInfo.SessToken;` rather than `User.SignonInfo user = new User.SignonInfo()`.  And the point is, that what he is asking for is not how nested types or static types work in C#.  If you don't have anything to contribute please go to another site.